# Need to show AM/PM with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to format some dates using MomentJS.  I have no problem until I try to add AM/PM or am/pm.  I have the following function and am passing in the time from the results of a Breeze EntityQuery where the time is a System.DateTime as shown:

```
function datetimeCellRendererFunc(value) {
    // value = Mon Jun 15 2015 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time);
    return moment(value).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
}
```

Whether I use A or a in the formatting, I still end up with the following:

> 06/15/2015 9:00 上午

Is there something else I need to add?  Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Are you using any localization?

Comment: No.  Do you normally need to add it?  I did use locale('en') as listed below and it worked.

Comment: I would assume you are using moment with all the localizations, i would suggest you download the moment.js only and you would not need to worry about localizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force the English locale globally, add

```
moment.locale('en');
```

to your code.

To configure it for a specific `moment` instance, you could also use

```
moment(value).locale('en').format(/* ... */);
```

in your function.

Comment: FYI - The issue with the default locale not being in English was fixed in the latest 2.10.6 release.  Update, and this code is then not required.